# Line integral (not using Stokes theorem)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate

$$\int_C Fdr$$

$$F=<-y^2,x,z^2>$$

$C$ is the curve of intersection of the plane $y+z=2$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$

I can parametrize the curve using cylindrical coordinates but I don't know exactly how I would do that when $x$ is missing from the plane equation. Any ideas?

Comment: Who is that guy Stoke?  Surely you mean Stokes!  So say *Stokes's theorem* or *Stokes' theorem*.

Comment: You have to give the curve $C$ a sense of direction. So far it is only a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about the equation for the plane $z+y=2$ ... $x$ spans from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Parametrically, let $u$ and $v$ span the plane.  Then, $x=u$, $y=v$, and $z=2-v$ is a parametric description that fits here.  Another is $x=u$, $y=2-v$, and $z=v$. Can you think of others?

Think about a plane that lies in the $x-y$ plane.  Here, $z=0$ defines the plane, while $x$ and $y$ span it.  So, $x=u$, $y=v$, and $z=0$ is a valid parameterization.

Now, on to the line integral itself.

---

Use of cylindrical coordinates would be a natural choice.  But I will go brute force.  This will provide a general outline for tackling similar problems for which there is no well-know curvilinear coordinate system to which you can appeal.

---

To that end, let $t$ be a parameter.

Then, there are two "pieces."

On "Piece 1," $x=\sqrt{1-t^2}$, $y=t$, and $z=2-t$, and $t$ starts at $-1$ and ends at $1$.

On "Piece 2," $x=-\sqrt{1-t^2}$, $y=t$, and $z=2-t$, and $t$ starts at $1$ and ends at $-1$.

Remember, that the differential line segment $d\vec r$ is given by

$$d\vec r =\hat x \frac{dx}{dt}+\hat y \frac{dy}{dt}+\hat z \frac{dz}{dt} dt$$
where
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\mp \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$ with the upper sign on "Piece 1," and the lower sign on "Piece 2." 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=1$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=-1$$

It won't be pretty, but it is tenable.

---

For the corresponding surface integral, let $u$ and $v$ be parameters.

Then, $\vec r=\hat x u+\hat yv+\hat z (2-v)$ with $-1\le u\le 1$ and $-\sqrt{1-u^2}\le v\le \sqrt{1-u^2}$ defining the surface.

The unit vector normal to the surface is

$$\hat n= \frac{\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial v}}{|\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial v}|}=\frac{\hat x \times (\hat y-\hat z)}{|\hat x \times (\hat y-\hat z)|}=\frac{\hat y+\hat z}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Again, a more natural setting for all of this would be a cylindrical coordinate system.  But, this does give you a way to proceed in cases for which there is no suitable well-known curvilinear coordinate system to use.

Comment: @Nash I hope that this helps.  Let me know if there is something else you would like to discuss.  I'd like to know that this was the "best" answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Parametrize it useing $x=\cos\theta$, $y=\sin\theta$ and $z=2-\sin\theta$.